# Populating Control values from a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, controls

I am new to C# so please fogive my newbie question.

I created a dictionary of controls from a Windows form called dictControls.  I then populated it with all text box and combobox controls and values from the form:

```
Dictionary<Control, string> dictFormControls = new Dictionary<Control, string>(); 
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
               dictFormControls.Add(c, ((ComboBox)c).SelectedValue.ToString()); 
            }
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
               dictFormControls.Add(c, ((TextBox)c).Text); 
            }
            if (c is MaskedTextBox)
            {
               dictFormControls.Add(c, ((MaskedTextBox)c).Text);
            }
        }

        if (discNumber <= Convert.ToInt32(numDiscs))
        {
         frmAddVideo frm = new frmAddVideo(numDiscs, discNumber, videoID, sequenceID, dictFormControls);
         frm.Show();
         this.Close();
        }
```

I want the dictionary basically look something like this:

**Key  ------------  Value**

"txtName"  -----     "Test"

"txtYear"  ------     "1980"

I am passing this back into the same form (frmAddVideo):

```
public frmAddVideo(string numDiscs, int discNumber, string videoID, string sequenceID, Dictionary<Control, string> dict)

    {
        this.numDiscs = numDiscs;
        this.discNumber = discNumber;
        this.videoID = videoID;
        this.sequenceID = sequenceID;
        InitializeComponent();

        //This is where I want to parse out the Dictionary and populate the form values
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, string> item in dict)
        {

            **Basically, I am looking for a way to take **            
            **item(Key)**
            **and do something like item(Key).Value = item(Value);**
            **so it would be the same as writing**
            **txtName.Text= "1980";**
            **cbxLocID.Value = 1;**
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to take key and turn it into the control name, then add ".Text" or ".Value" to it and then set the value to item(value) as I explained in the code above.

Is this possible?  I tried researching this, but I have yet to put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: Are you just trying to persist the data? If so, you might try serializing the form instead of manually saving everything.

Comment: If this is new, use WPF.

Comment: @Jodrell how is switching to WPF going to help him?

Comment: @Titan2782, Mark would be learning the recommended way of developing client GUI's as opposed to the legacy option offered for backward compatability.

Comment: Who says it's the recommended way, just because it's newer? If he's just learning C# then doing WPF is only going to complicate his learning as he has to wade through all of the WPF bs. Your comment isn't constructive.

Comment: First off, thatnks everyone for the responses.

I am new to c#, and basically I have a windows form that calls itself on Save.  I am trying to prepopulate a few text boxes and combo boxes with information from the form.  I thought I could do that by using a dictionary of the contols (key) and values (value), pass it back into a constructor, and loop through and parse out the key (which is the name of the control on the form) and the value.

I'm just doing this to learn.  I started with Windows forms so I could learn to crawl before I walk, so to speak. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may just store the set of controls you work with in your dictionary:

```
class ControlBoundValueDescription
{
  private Control _control;

  public ControlBoundValueDescription(Control control)
  {
    _control = control;
  }

  public string Value
  {
    get
    {
      if(_control is ...) return ...
      ...
    }

    set
    {
      if(_control is ...) ((Xxx)_control).Yyy = value;
      ...
    }
  }
}
...    
Dictionary<string, ControlBoundValueDescription> dictControls = 
  new Dictionary<string, ControlBoundValueDescription>(); 
...
// defining mappings (you may also want to populate it automatically,
// by iterating over all the controls you have on your form)
dictControls["UserName"] = new ControlBoundValueDescription(tbUserName);
dictControls["Group"] = new ControlBoundValueDescription(cbxGroup);
...
// working with controls using previously defined mappings
dictControls["UserName"].Value = "guest"; // probably, text box
dictControls["Group"].Value = "Guest Users"; // probably, combo
```

But the whole idea seems to be bad design. You should probably clarify the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I should -1 for using public field ;)

Comment: @Titan2782: Fixed specially for you ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry let me clarify what I am trying to do. I have a Windows form with some text boxes and combo boxes that calls itself upon clicking Save. I am trying to prepopulate a few text boxes and combo boxes with information from the form. I thought I could do that by using a dictionary of the contols (key) and values (value), pass it back into a constructor, and loop through and parse out the key (which is the name of the control on the form) and the value.

For example, let's say I have a text box called txtYear with a value of 1987. What I need:

dict<TKey,TValue>
dict<"txtYear",""1987">

Comment: "I have a Windows **form** with some text boxes and combo boxes that calls itself upon clicking Save. I am trying to prepopulate a few text boxes and combo boxes with information from the **form**". I don't get it :-) how many forms are there? Where does the data for prepopulation come from?

Comment: And also, please check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx and let us know whether it's what you're talking about :-)

Comment: It comes the form itself (frmAddVideo).  The Save_OnClick calls the form again:

frmAddVideo frm = new frmAddVideo(numDiscs, discNumber, videoID, sequenceID, dictFormControls);

What I was trying to do here is bring up the form again, and instead of it being blank, it would be prepopulated with a few of the values of the form from before I clicked Save.

1.  Fill out the the form.
2.  Click Save.
3.  Bring up the form again, with certain fields prepopulated from Step 1.

That's what I was going for.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, you have a form, where you type some data, then you click "save" and that causes this form to close. Then you want to show the same form once again (brand-new object in fact) and you want it to be populated with the data you've previously "saved". Is that correct?

Comment: In a way, yes. It's a small project to catalog my DVD collection.  Some DVDs set are more than 1 disc.  The 1st thing that happens is I specify how many discs the set is (ex. 3).  Then I enter information about the 1st DVD (name, run time, Disc#, etc) on the form.  I click save.  There is a ctr variable that checks which DVD I am entering. That information goes into a database and the ctr increases.  In the Save method, I then check to see if the ctr is <= the total # of discs. If there are more to enter, the form closes and a new one comes up with fields prepopulated from the previous form.

Comment: I have databinding working on the comboboxes and that works fine.  I have records going into the database fine as well.  The isue here is that I need certain field propulated from Disc 1 to Disc 2 when I am entering them, and since it is a new object that comes up (the form calls a new instnace of itself) there is no databinding there.  So, I thought I could use the text values from the Disc1 form and populate values on the Disc2 form that will then get saved to the database when Save is clicked for that one, and will carry over to Disc 3, etc.

Comment: Well, I believe that most reasonable approach of asking this question is just to write the piece of code you'd like to see when *using* the functionality you're asking about. Not pseudo-code, but real C#. In this case, it would be much easier to tell how to implement that functionality. From functional standpoint there are many approaches in achieving what you're saying and the one you decided to use not a de-facto solution. So, if we started with "I decided to do it this way" and "I want to write *these* 3 lines of code to get *these* results", it would be way easier :-)

Comment: OK, how about this?  What I want:  I want to prepopulate form control values from a Windows form into a new instance of the same form when a button is clicked.  I decided to do it this way:  In the butSave_Click method, I populated a Dictionary with the control as the key and value of the control as the value of the key.  I then pass that into a constructor on the page.  In that constructor, I want to assign the values in that Dictionary to the controls on the form.

Comment: `code`
foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, string> item in dict ) {
 if (item.Key is ComboBox) {
  ((ComboBox)item.Key).SelectedValue = item.Value;         
  }
 else if (item.Key is TextBox) {
  ((TextBox)item.Key).Text = item.Value;  
  }
 else if (item.Key is MaskedTextBox) {
  ((MaskedTextBox)item.Key).Text = item.Value; 
  }
}
`code`

Comment: The results I want to get:  txtYear.Value = "1987".  Sorry for all of these posts, this comment section is not really letting me type much. :)

Comment: BTW, @loki2302 thanks for your help.  I actually have the C# code I wrote and what I what accomplished in the first post of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use Find()

```
 ((TextBox)myForm.Controls.Find(Key, true)).Text = Value;
 ((CheckBox)myForm.Controls.Find(Key, true)).Checked = Boolean.Parse(Value);
```

Comment: You forgot [ListControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.aspx) which use SelectedValue